# check range is acceptable or not in expression a-b=c

Tags: javascript, math

I have to check whether given range is possible to generate a random numbers for expression a-b=c.

For example 
a range is 1 to 9 
b range is 1 to 9 and 
c range is 10 to 99

then in that case I have to return false.

My login is

```
  if (((a.Min - b.Min) <= c.Max) && ((a.Max - b.Min) >= c.Min))
     return true;
  else
     return false;
```

But this condition is failing in few cases.

Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: *this condition is failing in few cases* - can you post those cases?

Comment: It is failing in condition  like a is 101 to 999 , b is 1 to 9 and c is 10 to 99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct condition should be:

```
a.Max - b.Min <= c.Max
a.Min - b.Max >= c.Min
```

With your example: a = [101, 999], b = [1, 9]

The min number you can get is: a.Min - b.Max = 101 - 9 = 92

The max number is: 999 - 1 = 998

So your logic returns true when c = [92, 998] or any with min > 92, max < 998, like [100, 500]